# Pointer to struct's member

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I've found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454095/using-pointers-to-members-and-address-spaces-in-clang) a strange syntax:

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
    int baz;
};

typedef int foo::*foo_member;
foo_member m = &foo::bar;
```

I still do not understand the type `foo_member`, what does type `int foo::*` mean?

Even more confused, what is `&foo::bar` in the initialization

```
foo_member m = &foo::bar;
```

and

```
foo AS1* f = /* ... */;
f->*m = 4;
```

I suppose that means `f->bar = 4` (or not?), what does syntax `f->*_variable_` mean?

Many thanks for any response.

Comment: `int foo::*` represent a pointer to member syntax. It define a pointer to integer that is a foo member.

`foo_member m = &foo::bar; ` is storing the memory adress of the `foo::bar` member and storing in the pointer to member `foo_member m`.

Comment: @Clonk what's tripping me up is `foo` is a type, not an instance, and `bar` isn't static. If that's valid, and not just an oversight in the example, it's pretty odd.

Comment: It's a pointer to an int member not a pointer to integer. This is how you would use it : `foo f; std::cout << f.*m << std::endl; `

Comment: @Clonk: thanks. It is a confused syntax, IMHO, `int foo::*` is a pointer to a member, but which member?. Moreover `&foo:bar` is undefined? (since `foo` is a type?)

Comment: @Clonk Yeah, I'm reading the spec now. Just seems that the committee could have found a way to do that inside the struct definition. Oh, well. :)

Comment: `int foo::*` is a **type**. `&foo:bar` is an instance of this type if you will (it has the type `int foo::*`)

Comment: No `&foo::bar` is an object of type `int foo::*`, i.e. a "pointer to int member-of-foo". The valid values of `int foo::*` are `&foo::bar` and `&foo::baz`

Comment: @Clonk: sorry `int foo::*` is a pointer type to a member (of type `int`) of `foo`.

Comment: Consider: `foo_member m = (rand() % 2) ? &foo::bar : &foo::baz; foo f { 42, 0 }; std::cout << f.*m;` The output depends on the choice of member

Comment: That's pretty nifty.  Though, I'd probably just add a reference `int& getIt() { return (rand() % 2) ? bar : baz; }` Shrug.